# Adding markers to google earth

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I add new marker to the map? I managed to show the map `function startGoogleMaps()`
but my function (`onclick()`), does not work.

```
function startGoogleMaps(){    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvasMap'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: initCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });            
}

document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = function(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: (37, -97),
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"});
}
```

Comment: Where should the marker appear? I.e. what is position `(37, -97)`?

Comment: the issue was the `position: (37, -97)` need it to be `new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97)`

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript debugger? Get one right now, if you aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the `map` object in the same scope as you are binding the click event:

```
var map = null;

function startGoogleMaps(){    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvasMap'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: initCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });            
}

document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = function(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: (37, -97),
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"});
}
```

Also note that you need to pass your position as an instance of `google.maps.LatLng`:

```
      ...
      position: google.maps.LatLng(37, -97),
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Javascript uses functional scope. You'll need to declare `map` globally like so:

```
var map;

function startGoogleMaps(){    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvasMap'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: initCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });            
}

document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = function(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97),
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"});
}
```

In addition, the marker itself may be outside the scope of your map, so you can use `map.fitBounds` to display it properly:

```
document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = function(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97),
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"});

    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    latlngbounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97));
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
}
```

Comment: when I use th `map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);` my map disappears